# Will DROP TABLE of an empty table with a large tablespace file cause a long lock?

Tags: mysql, percona

Let's say I have a reasonably large (100GB) INNODB table on a 3-node Percona Xtradb Cluster that uses `innodb_file_per_table=1` and has about 80GB buffer_pool per node and uses `ext4`. I want to drop this large table without causing any global lock. I use this approach:

- I delete all the rows from the table with `pt-archiver`. At this point the table is empty, but the innodb file for that table is still ~100GB.
- I issue a `DROP TABLE tablename`

Will I get any global lock due to either `ws-rep` or the fact that Innodb has to go through the LRU list and discard the pages which belong to this tablespace?

Comment: Next time, do a rolling `DROP TABLE`.

Comment: I'm asking this before doing it.

Comment: If you do it rolling (a la RSU `ALTER`), you get to see how long it takes without hurting production.

Answer (score 0):

What version of MySQL are you using?

I'd do a RENAME table then delete rows in chunks (something like `DELETE FROM TABLE LIMIT 5000;` in a loop) once it's empty you should be able to drop it.

Adjust the LIMIT 5000 up or down depending on how long that operation takes, slave replication falls behind, or it's affecting other queries performance.

If it's an empty table then no, it shouldn't cause a long lock.